# How to find unique users in each level, who hasn't been present in the previous levels using Google BigQuery?

Tags: mysql, sql, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to find out unique user(s) who has started a level and that user(s) should not be included in any other levels. When I use distinct, each level's distinct users are displayed who may or may not have played the previous levels. How should I go about it?

The query i'm running is

```
  SELECT
  event_name,
  chapter_name,
  level_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS uniques,
  COUNT(id) AS total
FROM
  `abc.analytics_188353913.level`
WHERE
   (first_open between "2020-01-20" AND "2020-01-26")
 AND platform = "ANDROID" 
  AND event_name = "level_start"

GROUP BY
 event_name,
  chapter_name,
  level_name
```

I need to find user who is counted only once. Is that possible? eg. If a user visits level 2, 3 and 4 this query will count him in each levels. I need to count the user only on level 2 and not the rest i.e if a user starts any level he won't be counted on subsequent levels.

Comment: I think you need to include some sample table data here, and also show us the expected output, along with an explanation on that.

Comment: *user(s) who has started a level and that user(s) should not be included in any other levels.* If so then grouping by level is wrong. You must group by user only, and check (in `HAVING`) that `COUNT(level)` (or `COUNT(DISTINCT level)`, if duplicates by level for a user are possible) is equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks Akina! But the issue is each chapter has about 40 levels and the number of users on each level is > 40k.

Comment: @Sushan, could you provide some dummy sample data so I can minimally reproduce your case ?

Comment: @Sushan . . . I would advise you to delete this question.  Then ask another question.  Provide sample data and desired results.  Clearly describe the problem *in terms of your data*.  Explain what YOU mean by "counted only once".

Comment: @GordonLinoff counted only once means if a user visits 3 different levels, I would want to consider him only on one level and remove him from the rest of the 2 levels.

Comment: @Sushan, can you provide sample data and desired output? Also, what is the rule for keep the user ( which level should I consider?)?